# create war file in tomcat and create web-inf

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, web-inf

I have a java project that use tomcat. when I run project in idea with tomcat(version 6)my project run in idea and in tomcat not create web inf file for my project and war file. why?

thanks

Comment: Because you must provide `WEB-INF` directory by yourself, Tomcat won't make it for you, it's only extract the `war` file so it could be executed trough Tomcat

Comment: Do you want to create `war` file or `WEB-INF` directory or both? And which build tool are you using?

Answer (score -3):

It should be a web project not java project and Tomcat is not responsible for creating web-inf folder. It is created when you first defined the project. Also are you able to see your war after building ? Does it launch the browser when you say running in Tomcat?

Comment: Your answer seems to be a lot of questions for the OP. This should have been a comment at best.

Comment: After running project that use tomcat. in tomcat path I dont see war file and in webapp folder is not web-inf file. I run project in idea 15. I found my problem. in config tomcat server from idea for deployment in application context I dont select good path. when I change it this is ok.

Comment: It's funny how I got downvoted for not adding the answer as comment. I am glad that it is working for you now.